# django-editlive: no template variable

Tags: jquery, python, django

I am having a problem with [django-editlive](http://editlive.motion-m.ca/). An error keeps popping up at the Linux terminal: ***editlive: the template variable "lecture.topic_title" doesn't exists.***, but I am sure that the code is OK, because the objects are showing as they supposed to without editlive app. I have tried downgrading Django from 1.5.1 to 1.4.something but it did not help. The dajaxice, editlive and bootstrap css / js files are loaded properly. Maybe anyone has experience with the same problem ? I am not sure what to do.

My models (Note Lecture model) are:

```
from django.db import models
from lynx import settings



class BaseModel(models.Model):
date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
time = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Meta:
    abstract = True


class Title(BaseModel): #Lecture 1, lecture 2, etc. TODO: title time
number = models.IntegerField("lecture number", default="1")


def __unicode__(self):
    return self.number


class Topic(BaseModel):
name = models.TextField()

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name


class Summary(BaseModel):
content = models.TextField(max_length=1000)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.content

class Lecture(BaseModel):
number = models.ForeignKey(Title)
topic_title = models.OneToOneField(Topic)
summary = models.OneToOneField(Summary)
```

Corresponding view:

```
def App(request):
lectures = Lecture.objects.all()
return render (request, "app.html", {"lectures" : lectures,})
```

And my template part:

```
{% for lecture in lectures %}
{%load editlive_tags%}
{%editlive "lecture.topic_title" as bla%}
<h2>{{ bla }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens when the database column is missing, so I would look for that (and typos).

For example, if you built the model, did syncdb and then added another field to your model. The django admin might not complain about it, neither the template engine which will just ignore it. But django-editlive will choke on it.

Make sure that the topic_title column really exists in your database.

I also see other potential problem sources ..

The `load` tag should not be invoked within a for loop;

```
{% load editlive_tags %}
{% for lecture in lectures %}
{% editlive "lecture.topic_title" as bla %}
<h2>{{ bla }}</h2>
{% endfor %}
```

You can test that the problem doesn't come from editlive being used in the for loop like so;

```
{% load editlive_tags %}
{% with lecture=lectures.0 %}
{% editlive "lecture.topic_title" as bla %}
<h2>{{ bla }}</h2>
{% endwith %}
```

Finally, Django-editlive should work with most Django versions, but it was developed against Django 1.5.

Hope this will help you !

Comment: Hello. I am sorry for answering just now. Actually the problem still exists.. I have tried to drop and re-create tables and to load editlive tags before the for loop and I have again downgraded Django to 1.4.2 and then to 1.4.9 but it still does not show anything between <h2> tags... Maybe you have any other idea why it still tells me "editlive: the template variable "lecture.topic_title" doesn't exists.". Maybe there are some tests to run or something ?... And maybe you know any alternatives to your app (at the worst case) ?